# finding similarities for a R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, similarity

I have two groups of data frames (A and B). An example data frame from group A is `data1` and an example data frame from group B is `data2`

Data frames look like:

`data1`

```
                              data
1                             apple
2            orange | apple | mango
3                             apple
4                            banana
5                            grapes
6                            papaya
7                            durian
8 tomato | orange | papaya | durian
```

`data2`

```
                                data
1  papaya | durian | orange | grapes
2                             orange
3                             grapes
4                    banana | durian
5                             tomato
6                     apple | tomato
7                              apple
8                        mangostine 
9                         strawberry
10                strawberry | mango
```

notes:

1. Both data frames have one column, the name of this column is `data`.
2. First data frame and second data frame have different rows.

I've tried Levenshtein distance between two rows.

```
library(RecordLinkage)
> levenshteinSim("apple", "apple")
[1] 1
> levenshteinSim("apple", "aaple")
[1] 0.8
> levenshteinSim("apple", "appled")
[1] 0.8333333
> levenshteinSim("appl", "apple")
[1] 0.8
```

My question is: I want to measure the similarity score from two data frames, for example the similarity score of `data1`  and `data2`.

Is there someone who can shed some light on this for me?

Comment: So you're looking for an overall number giving you an idea of the similarity of 2 databases, correct?

Comment: Yes, probably we can say that, my situation is, I have two folder `model` and `test`, both of folder has many of files, the name of files inside both of folder is same but different contents, so I want to measure the similarity from the content of files inside both of folder. do you understand what I mean? sorry for my english

Comment: Hmmm yes I think I understand. I'm just not sure R is the best tool for this. Let me think about it for a minute... What OS are you using?